# ASP.NET MVC Get image path from different module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

For sample I got these two modules.
Module.Admin
Module.Web

Then, all images that are uploaded inside the Module.Admin is place inside it, sitemap goes like this.
Module.Admin
- Content
-- Uploads
--- Images

Now, how can I load as  source these images inside the Module.Web > View .cshtml file?
As I've notice, these two modules are having two different ports. I hope you understand what I'm saying. Feel free to ask. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you made the module a web project too? That means that they will run in seperate sites and not be able to share information.

You should probably use plugins instead. I've described how you can do it in my blog: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/

If you only want to access files you have to setup a custom `VirtualPathProvider` which can access the files from the other library.